# HOW TO SUBTRACT LAST ENTERANCE WITH PREVIOUS ONE

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, lookup

I need help, I have been trying for hours to figure this out.

I need to keep track of material consumption and report it weekly so I need to subtract previous value of some material from current one.

I have tried with VLOOKUP, INDEX, LOOKUP but didn't get the desired results.

Excel table can be downloaded from link:
https://easyupload.io/kziudk

[Click here for image of Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0NU5.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: The word your looking for is subtract, substrack, isn’t a word.  You should [edit] your question and address the issues in your question, be sure you don’t add any unnecessary noise.  You should provide the table within your question, with sample data, making it clear what the input and output should be.  Additionally, uploading the image, instead of an external website is ideal

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for corrections. Excel table picture and table provided in link are pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to subtract the value on the current row from the previous value in the same column (Total consumed) within the same group (BOX_ID), as determined by INPUT_ID.

This will work:

```
=[@[TOTAL_CONSUMED]]-IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MAXIFS([INPUT_ID],[BOX_ID],[@[BOX_ID]],[INPUT_ID],"<"&[@[INPUT_ID]]),Table1[[INPUT_ID]:[TOTAL_CONSUMED]],3,FALSE),0)
```

To see why it works, consider the green colored intermediate columns in this image:

[image]

This can possibly be done with OFFSET, but I don't recommend that.

If you have the most recent version of Excel, you can also try this slightly simpler formula where `MAX(FILTER(` is used in place of `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MAXIFS(`

```
=[@[TOTAL_CONSUMED]]-MAX(FILTER([TOTAL_CONSUMED],([BOX_ID]=[@[BOX_ID]])*([INPUT_ID]<[@[INPUT_ID]]),0))
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out later. I found something also but it needs some tweaking.